# Firebase not showing in onCreate

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to show a listView in the beginning of the activity where the entries are in the firebase but however the activity is not showing anything and when i click on somewhere on the screen the onItemClickListener works

i thing the problem is because the onDataChange works only where there's changes in the database

in the layout the visibility all set to true so it's not about the visibility

```
public class ViewUploads extends AppCompatActivity{

    //the listview
    ListView listView;

    //database reference to get uploads data
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

    //list to store uploads data
    List<Upload> uploadList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_uploads);

        uploadList = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);





        //adding a clicklistener on listview
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                //getting the upload
                Upload upload = uploadList.get(i);

                //Opening the upload file in browser using the upload url
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(upload.getUrl()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        //getting the database reference
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

        //retrieving upload data from firebase database
        mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    uploadList.add(upload);
                }

                String[] uploads = new String[uploadList.size()];

                for (int i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) {
                    uploads[i] = uploadList.get(i).getName();
                }

                //displaying it to list
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, uploads);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }



}
```

Comment: no thats not a reason.

Comment: you didn't mentioned which child you want to fetch.

Comment: show your database and which node you want to access?

Comment: Can you add what do you get iterating over this? (using prints)

"dataSnapshot.getChildren()"

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `String data = upload.getData();` below `Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);`

Here getData(); method represents the getter method of the node in your firebase....just replace getData with your own method